# kubernetes - version issues when adding new node to existing cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pre-existing k8 cluster that I want to add a node to. It appears that there's a version issue and Im not sure how to resolve it.

When I attempt to join the new node (using `kubeadm join`):

```
...
[kubelet] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.12" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace      
configmaps "kubelet-config-1.12" is forbidden: User "system:bootstrap:rsezn8" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"
```

On an existing node:

```
[root@kube0 ~]# kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:43:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
[root@kube0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep kube
kubeadm-1.12.1-2.x86_64
kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-2.x86_64
kubectl-1.12.1-2.x86_64
kubelet-1.12.1-2.x86_64
```

On the (putative) new node:

```
[root@kube4 ~]# rpm -qa | grep kube
kubectl-1.12.1-0.x86_64
kubelet-1.12.1-0.x86_64
kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64
kubeadm-1.12.1-0.x86_64
```

On the master node:

```
[root@kube-master kubernetes]# kubectl get configmap -n kube-system
NAME                                 DATA   AGE
coredns                              1      106d
extension-apiserver-authentication   6      106d
filebeat-config                      1      16d
filebeat-inputs                      1      16d
kube-proxy                           2      106d
kubeadm-config                       1      106d
kubelet-config-1.11                  1      106d
kubernetes-dashboard-settings        1      105d
weave-net                            0      106d
[root@kube-master kubernetes]# kubelet --version
Kubernetes v1.12.1
```

When I look at previous solutions to this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380934/unable-to-connect-worker-node-to-kubernetes-cluster)) it seems like the new node is **higher** version than the existing. In my case the opposite is (somehow) true. (`yum update` doesn't show any newer versions)

Another issue is the **kubelet-config-1.11**. Is that my issue here? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to follow the std upgrade process. Somehow I had a system with kubeadm version 1.21.1 and cluster version 1.11.0.

Followed the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-12/).

When it came to downloading new software it was already on the system(s).